# A compactification of the space of points on the affine line

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, rt.representation-theory

I recently encountered an interesting space.  It is a compactification of the space of $ n$ points in $ \mathbb A^1 $ modulo translation, $ (\mathbb A^1)^n / \mathbb G_a $.

Let $ n \in \mathbb N $ and let $ p([n]) = \{ (i,j) \in \{1, \dots, n\}^2 : i \ne j \} $.  Let $ Y_n $ be the subscheme of $ (\mathbb P^1)^{p([n])} $ defined by the equations
$$ 
\tau_{ik} = \tau_{ij} + \tau_{jk} \quad \tau_{ij} = -\tau_{ji}
$$

If we restrict to the open set $ Y_n^{\circ} $ where $ \tau_{ij} \ne \infty $, then we have an isomorphism $ Y_n^\circ \cong (\mathbb A^1)^n / \mathbb G_a $ where $ \tau_{ij} = x_i - x_j $.

In fact, $Y_n $ has a stratification with strata
$$ (\mathbb A^1)^{S_1} / \mathbb G_a \times \cdots \times (\mathbb A^1)^{S_m} / \mathbb G_a$$
where $ \{1, \dots, n \} = S_1 \sqcup \cdots \sqcup S_m $.

Another interesting thing about $Y_n $ is that it is the degeneration of the permutahedral toric variety (also known as the Losev-Manin space).  This latter space can be realized as a subscheme of $ (\mathbb P^1)^{p([n])} $ by the equations
$$ \alpha_{ij} \alpha_{jk} = \alpha_{ik} \quad \alpha_{ij} = \alpha_{ji}^{-1} $$

**Has anyone seen this space before?**

Comment: Have you worked out what (if any) the objects parametrized by the boundary look like? A first guess is that this might be related to Hassett's moduli spaces of rational curves with weighted marked points.

Comment: And on a more aesthetic note, is there a reason you've written $p([n])$ instead of $p(n)$? I only ask because on my first time reading that definition I was momentarily expecting dependence on some residue class instead of $n$ itself.

Comment: I used $[n]$ to denote $ \{1, \dots, n \} $, as is standard in combinatorics.  I agree it could be confused with residue classes.

Comment: As I wrote above, the boundary parametrizes collections of affine lines each carrying some marked points.  I view these affine lines as being attached at their $\infty $ points, so that the resulting curve looks like a flower.  For this reason, we call this a flower space.  But I don't know if this can be made precise.

Comment: Update: Pavel Etingof pointed us to the following paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0105095.pdf by Terao.  In Example 1.6, he studies the subalgebra of rational functions generated by $ 1/ x_i - x_j $.  The Spec of this algebra is an open subset of $Y_n$, namely the locus $ \tau_{ij} \ne 0 $.

Comment: Update #2: it seems that Evens and Li have been studying this space as well.  They call it the compactification of the Cartan subalgebra of $ \mathfrak{sl}_n $ and they study these spaces for other semisimple Lie algebras as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given a linear space $L \subset \mathbb{A}^n$, the closure of $L$ inside of $(\mathbb{P}^1)^n$ is called the **Schubert variety** of $L$, or of the hyperplane arrangement obtained by intersecting the coordinate hyperplanes with $L$.  Your variety is the Schubert variety of the Coxeter arrangement of type $A_{n-1}$.

The Schubert variety was introduced by Ardila and Boocher https://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.6874.pdf.  The stratification is not explicitly studied there, but it was observed both by Huh and Wang https://arxiv.org/pdf/1609.05484.pdf (who used it to prove the top-heavy conjecture for realizable matroids, which features prominently in Huh's Fileds Medal citation) and by Young, Xu, and myself https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.05575.pdf.  If you blow up first the point stratum, then the strict transforms of the 1-dimensional strata, and so on, you obtain the **augmented wonderful variety** https://arxiv.org/pdf/2010.06088.pdf, which is the topic of a lot of current research.  The induced stratification of the affine patch in which all coordinates are nonzero (called the **reciprocal plane**, or the spectrum of the **Orlik--Terao algebra**) was first studied much earlier by Speyer and myself https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0410069.pdf.

Sometimes the Schubert variety of a hyperplane arrangement is referred to as a **matroid Schubert variety**, since its cohomology ring is a matroid invariant (called the **graded Mobius algebra**), as is its intersection cohomology module.  But that's kind of sloppy terminology, as the isomorphism type of the variety itself is not determined by the matroid.

In the case that you describe, $Y_n$ can be regarded as the compactification of the configuration space of $n$ labeled points in $\mathbb{A}^1$ up to translation in which the distances between points are allowed to go either to zero or to infinity.  The stratification that you describe comes from asking which collections of points are a finite distance away from each other, which gives a partition of the set $[n]$.  This particular case was studied in detail by Young and myself https://arxiv.org/pdf/1704.04510.pdf.

Comment: Do you know an example where two different realizations of a matroid produce non-isomorphic "matroid Schubert varieties"?

Comment: If $L$ is a hyperplane in $\mathbb{A}^n$ that does not contain any coordinate line, then it realizes the uniform matroid of rank $n-1$ on the set $[n]$.  I don't have a proof off the top of my head that there are two such $L$ whose closures are not isomorphic, but I would be very surprised if they were all isomorphic.